# Java - alternative to InputStreamReader?

Tags: java

**Has been resolved. Ignore**

I have an `InputStream` that provides lines of output at set intervals. I need this wrapped up in a `BufferedReader` somewhere else, so I tried wrapping it up in an `InputStreamReader` with

```
myReader = new InputStreamReader(new MyStream(soureFile,interval));
```

However, now `myReader` blocks at the first `read()` until my stream made the entire output available. Is there some alternative to InputStreamReader that doesn't do that?

(Just for sake of completeness: Yes, I tested my InputStream - it's really the InputStreamReader that's doing the blocking).

Comment: Give code. What exactly method of the reader are you calling? The no-arg `read`?

Comment: I'm calling the no arg read on the reader. My own class works as expected with all 3 read methods, so I'm not sure what kind of value giving the code could possibly provide.

Comment: Since you say you've tested it, I won't ask if you have a Buffered writer on the other side ;)

Comment: This won't be settled without seeing your implementation code.

Comment: I'm actually under a NDA, but since this is just a small helper class this should be fine I guess. Added the code.

Comment: An NDA doesn't stop you from providing a small, self-contained compilable example.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I forgot to implement the byte[] read methods. I now changed it so it wouldn't try to read more than what's already available, and it works now.